# How to solve this exponential inequality?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the exponential inequality $$8^x +18^x -2\cdot 27^x>0.$$ I tried

```
Solve[8^x + 18^x - 2*27^x > 0, x]
```

and

```
Reduce[8^x + 18^x - 2*27^x > 0, x]
```

How do I tell *Mathematica* to do that?

Comment: "I tried...", but you don't say what's wrong with the outcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Reduce[8^x + 18^x - 2 27^x > 0, x, Reals]
(*
 x<0
*)
```

Verifying

```
Plot[8^x + 18^x - 2*27^x, {x, -6, 3/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]